# Classification report de Sklearn, mi precisión es siempre 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos, machine-learning

Estoy teniendo problemas con los resultados de `classification_report()` de `sklearn` en una clasificación binaria en un data set desbalanceado, este es mi código:

1. dividir la data en 60% train, 20% validation, 20% teset

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x1, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
```

2. Sobremuestrear o submuestrear la clase minoritaria (en este caso submuestrear):

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
 
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=1)
X_resampled, y_resampled = rus.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)
```

3. Entrenar el modelo y predecir con el test (después de haberlo probado con validación cruzada)

```
model=LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_sm, y_sm)
y_pred=model.predict(X_test)
```

4. Métricas de sklearn (matriz de confusión y classification report)

```
matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(matrix)

sns.heatmap(matrix, annot=True, cbar=False, linecolor='black',linewidths=0.7, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,fmt='g' )
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Expected')
plt.show()

report = classification_report(y_test, preds)
print(report)
```

Dando como resultado lo que se observa en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mi duda es porque teniendo esa matriz de confusión la precisión de la clase positiva es 0, ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Tu programación y la representación que haces está bien! Lo único que te falta es saber exactamente como se calculan, y para que sirven las métricas de clasificación que estás usando, además de entender la salida de `classification_report()`.

**Voy a dar una respuesta amplia de todo lo que está sucediendo, y explicando la función de precisión por si le sirve a más usuarios de la comunidad.**

#### Output de classification_report()

`classification_report()` te da un output con dos decimales como máximo, si quieres ampliarlo a más puedes hacer esto.

```
classification_report(y_test, preds, digits=4) #ampliamos a 4 decimales
```

#### Cálculo de "precisión"

[image: [![formula de la precisión][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL1SW.png.]

Esta formula sirve para saber como de bien, está clasificando tu modelo los resultados positivos. **Simplemente selecciona los que han sido clasificados como positivos de forma correcta y los divide entre los positivos totales** 197 / (197 + 56.211).

1. Tus True negative (verdaderos negativos) son 120.979. Es decir el modelo ha clasificado 120.979 negativos, y efectivamente **ha acertado** porque eran negativos.
2. Tus false negatives (negativos falsos) son 56.211. Es decir el modelo ha clasificado 56.211 negativos, y **ha fallado** porque en realidad son positivos.
3. Tus False Negative (falsos negativos) son 70. Es decir el modelo ha clasificado 70 positivos, y **ha fallado** porque en realidad son negativos
4. Tus True positive (verdaderos positivos) son 197. Es decir el modelo ha clasificado 197 positivos, y efectivamente **ha acertado** porque eran positivos.

**Teniendo toda la información anterior en cuenta, aplicamos la fomula de la precisión**

True positive (197) / True positive (197) + False Positive (56.211).

Esto nos arroja un resultado de 0.0035. **Como classification report por defecto solo nos devuelve dos dígitos**, tu resultado es 0.00

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, agradezco tu ayuda!!